# discord.js14 - event starts to send endless messages after a while (reactionadded)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
const { MessageReaction, Events, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require("discord.js");

const reactionConfig = {
    channelID: "1078339846172573778",
    targetChannelID: "972616312952070144",
    messageID: "1078355581435379723",
    firstEmoji: "926995541596962919",
    staffRoleID: "886867243076567071",
    normalRoleID: "886869696752803890",
}

module.exports = {
    name: "messageReactionAdd",

    /**
     * 
     * @param {MessageReaction} reaction
     */

    async execute(reaction) {
        const client = reaction.client;

        if (reaction.partial) {
            try {
                await reaction.fetch();
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Something went wrong when fetching the message:', error);
                return;
            }
        }

        const channel = client.channels.cache.get(reactionConfig.channelID)
        const msg = await channel.messages.fetch(reactionConfig.messageID)

        if(msg){
        const collector = msg.createReactionCollector( 'time: 10000ms');

            collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
                switch (reaction.emoji.id){
                    case reactionConfig.firstEmoji: {
                    await client.channels.cache.get(reactionConfig.targetChannelID).send(`<@&${reactionConfig.staffRoleID}> - ${user} want to get Wookiee role. Please take action and check requirements!`)}
                collector.stop();
                    break;
                }
            })

        }
    }

}
```

The click on the emoji should trigger my bot to send a message to `targetchannel`. It works for a while - after another while the bot starts to send endless messages when someone is clicking that emoji once.

What do I oversee here?

Thank you!

Comment: What is this? `msg.createReactionCollector( 'time: 10000ms')`. It takes an object, not a string like that: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ReactionCollectorOptions

Comment: Oh I was going with the Options to be applied to the collector.

Comment: Okay, but when should i set the collector to stop? I wish I would have found another workaround for sending this ping message, but that was all I could do (sorry, I am JS newie)

Comment: I see. I'm not really sure what you want to do with this code. At the moment you add a bunch of reaction collectors using `msg.createReactionCollector` because you set up a new one on every reaction. Do you want to use `messageReactionAdd` to check if someone is reacting to a certain message (`reactionConfig.messageID`) with `firstEmoji`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you add a bunch of reaction collectors using `msg.createReactionCollector` because you set up a new one on every reaction. But I don't think you need to create a reaction collector.

If you want to check if someone is reacting to a certain message (`reactionConfig.messageID`) with `firstEmoji`, you can use the `messageReactionAdd` event with a simple if statement inside the callback function and check the value of `reaction.message.id` and `reaction.emoji.id`:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'messageReactionAdd',
  async execute(reaction, user) {
    if (reaction.partial) {
      try {
        await reaction.fetch();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Something went wrong when fetching the message:', error);
        return;
      }
    }

    if (
      reaction.message.id === reactionConfig.messageID &&
      reaction.emoji.id === reactionConfig.firstEmoji
    ) {
      let targetChannel = await reaction.client.channels.cache.get(
        reactionConfig.targetChannelID,
      );

      try {
        await targetChannel.send(
          `<@&${reactionConfig.staffRoleID}> - ${user} want to get Wookiee role. Please take action and check requirements!`,
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Something went wrong when sending the message:', error);
      }
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Yeah, what I wanted is really only to check if someone is clicking this emoji attached to this message and if clicked then it shoukd send 1 ping each time someone is clicking, nothing more. At first I thought it was a caching issue as when I started the botx it worked as intended, after half and hour it started to misbehave

Comment: So does the code above work as expected?

Comment: I am running it right now, need to wait a while. I will come back in 30-60mins and check if it still works as intended. Thank you very very much so far! 

Comment: No misbehavior anymore, works as intended. Thank you very very much!!